# jQuery select dynamically generated Tabs

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, selector

I am using Bootstrap and have Tabs that are created dynamically. Although they are dynamic, I will only create 3 Tabs. They are: Draft, Published and Archived. These are actually Enums.

When I click on a tab, I want to change a hidden field to the same value of the tab so that  when Postback occurs, I wish to open the selected that was previously opened.

The tabs id is #i where i is the iterator within the for loop. So the Tabs will be: #0, #1 and #2.

Does anyone know how I can create one onclick event for all the tabs and make the hidden field's value change to that of the Tabs id.

This is the the code:

```
<div class="tab-content">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.WorkflowStatuses.Count; i++)
    {
        <div class="tab-pane @(i == 0 ? "active" : string.Empty)" id="@i">
```

**EDIT**
This is what I have so far - The hidden field's value isn't changing however:

```
<script>
$('#listingTab a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show', function (e) {
    $('#selectedTab').val($(e.target).prop('id'));
})
```

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>Model.SelectedTab)

@if (Model.AnyListings)
{
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="listingTab">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.WorkflowStatuses.Count; i++)
```

**EDIT**
 I have added the letterl "t" but the hidden value still doesn't change:

```
<script>
    $('#tab-content a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show', function (e) {
        $('#SelectedTab').val($(e.target).prop('id'));
    })
</script>

@Html.HiddenFor(m=>Model.SelectedTab)

@if (Model.AnyListings)
{
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="listingTab">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.WorkflowStatuses.Count; i++)
        {
            <li class="@(i == 0 ? "active" : string.Empty)"><a href="@string.Format("#t{0}", i)" data-toggle="tab">@Model.WorkflowStatuses[i].ToString()</a></li>
        }
```

Comment: jQuery version?  ID cannot start with a number per 1999 spec and must be unique on the page.  Show your markup and what you have tried in code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `show` [event](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs) which fires whenever the active tab is changed:

```
$('#yourTabControl a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show', function (e) {
  $('#hiddenField').val($(e.target).prop('id'));
})
```

**[EDIT]:**

After a chat we concluded the `e.target` is the link you clicked on, not the tab it activated. So to keep the code a bit easier I suggested to use a `data-tabid` attribute on the link:

```
<li class="@(i == 0 ? "active" : string.Empty)">
  <a href="@string.Format("#t{0}", i)" data-toggle="tab" 
     data-tabid="@i">@Model.WorkflowStatuses[i].ToString()</a></li>
```

And use that in the event handler:

```
$('#yourTabControl a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show', function (e) {
  $('#hiddenField').val($(e.target).data('tabid'));
})
```

Comment: As mentioned by others, your id for the tab cannot be just a number. Change it to: `<div class="tab-pane @(i == 0 ? "active" : string.Empty)" id="t@i">`. That way each tab id starts with a 't'.

Comment: Hi - I have made the changes but it still doesn't work. I've added t before the number. Any ideas?

Comment: Try changing `prop` to `attr` when setting the value: `$(e.target).attr('id')`. Also, try debugging in Chrome/IE developer tools and setting a breakpoint in the function, so you can see what the id of `e.target' is.

Comment: And one more thought after looking through your code again: I don't think `@Html.HiddenFor(m=>Model.SelectedTab)` sets the id of the generated hidden input field. So therefore it wouldn't find it in the event handler. Try changing it to: `@Html.HiddenFor(m=>Model.SelectedTab, new { id = "SelectedTab" })`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23702/discussion-between-tom-van-enckevort-and-subby)

Answer (score 1):

Can't you give your tabs a class and then bind to them like this:

```
$(".tabs").on('click', function() {
 $('#my_input').val($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Also, you need to start your tabs ID tags with a letter. e.g. #t1, #t2, etc..

Answer (score 1):

use Live event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.

Give a common class to all the generated tabs so the live event binder will bind to all newly create tabs also

```
$("a.offsite").live("click", function(){
    alert("Hi!");
    //Your code
});
```

refer http://api.jquery.com/live/

Hope this helps